# Download 32bit OpenSSL using HomeBrew on 64bit Mac

Tags: macos, 64-bit, 32-bit, openssl, homebrew

- I have a 64 bit Mac
- I have a 32 bit app
- 32bit app needs OpenSSL
- I have tried point it OpenSSL downloaded by HomeBrew, but it fails

After having eliminated all other causes as well as possible, I have startted pondering it it could be a 32bit app versus 64bit dylib issue? If so, how can I force download of 32bit openssl binaries?

Answer (score 1):

Install openssl like this in command line: *brew install openssl --universal*

You may need to uninstall first using: *brew uninstall openssl*

Comment: OpenSSL is *not* universal-binary safe. Special care needs to be taken when using OpenSSL as a universal binary. Do you know if HomeBrew pays attention to the details?

Comment: @jww can you elaborate on that statement or do you have a reference?

Comment: It appears it no longer supports the `--universal` flag: `Warning: openssl: this formula has no --universal option so it will be ignored!`